# Error with Nodemailer in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, express, nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer to set up forgot password functionality. For some reason my code gets hung up in the smtpTrans.sendMail part. Am I correctly setting up Nodemailer?

UPDATE: Take a look at the full code below including the async.waterfall code

```
app.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          console.log('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
          return res.redirect('/forgot');
        }
console.log('step 1')
        user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
          done(err, token, user);
        });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
        console.log('step 2')
      var smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
         service: 'Hotmail', 
        auth: {
          user: 'myemailinfo@email.com',
          pass: '**********'
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {

        to: user.email,
        from: 'myemailinfo@email.com',
        subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
        text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
          'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
          'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
          'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'

      };
      console.log('step 3')
   smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
       console.log(err)
        req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
        done(err, 'done');
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log(err)
    res.redirect('/forgot');
  });
});

app.get('/forgot', function(req, res) {
  res.render('forgot', {
    user: req.user
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that the `console.log` calls in the `sendMail` callback never show up? Your code seems to be part of an `async` workflow (perhaps `async.waterfall()`?) but I don't see you calling the callback for that, which would cause a stall.

Comment: @robertklep Wow you're 100% right with on the async.waterfall(). I updated my code to show the full function. Am I missing the callback? Thanks!

Comment: At first glance, that looks okay. Have you tried running the Nodemailer part from a standalone script, just to see if it works there? Perhaps connecting to the Hotmail server takes a really long time.

Comment: @robertklep Interesting thought! Let me try switching it up. Thank you!

Comment: @robertklep Heck of a call! I switched to using Gmail and it worked perfectly. I never would have thought that was the only error so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodemailer [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/usage/#sending-mail) indicates the `callback` provided to `sendMail` takes a second parameter `info`.  So you might try something like this:

```
smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    if (info) {
        console.log(info.response)
    }

    req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
    done(err, 'done');
});
```

If the callback is invoked, `info.response` may be populated with some response from the SMTP mailer to give you an indication why it isn't working as you expected.

If the callback is never invoked, it might be that the service is not responding and the call isn't timing out.  You can also provide custom timeout values in the [SMTP options](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/)

One final note:  Hotmail has a daily limit of 100 messages via SMTP, so you should consider using a different provider.